# Title and text not quite the same

Tags: discussion

I'm looking at [What is the purpose of increasing the minimum wage?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/429/what-is-the-purpose-of-increasing-the-minimum-wage/515#515) which asks in the question, "is there an economic reason as to why a higher minimum wage would benefit the economy?"

I view these as two distinct questions, the first one can become political, the second, hopefully remaining 100% economic.

Should the title be edited to just the question contained in text itself?

Note: As a new member to Economics, I don't want to just offer an edit of that type without asking here, first.

Comment: It makes sense to me. Maybe we could ask the OP and see what he/she thinks? I don't know, though.

Comment: You would still have to define a measure for "benefit the economy": Lower unemployment? Higher growth? What? Since there are still situations where not all socio-economic classes benefit, you must at least define the "benefit" part and _stress_ that it does not bear a more general "value-judgement" meaning. Otherwise it will be still political